# $.ajax( { async : false } ) request is still firing asynchronously?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ajax, jquery

I got a little problem here guys. I'm trying to implement the following scenario:

1. A user opens the home page and sees a list of other users and clicks
   to add one to his friend list.
2. I issue an Ajax request to a server resource to validate if the user
   is logged in, if so, I issue another ajax request to another server
   resource to actually add it to the user's friend list.

Sounds simple? Here's what I've done: I created a function `isLoggedIn` that will issue the first request to the server in order to determine if the user is logged in. I issue this request using `jQuery.ajax` method. Here's my function looks like:

```
function isLoggedIn() {

    $.ajax({
    async: "false",
        type: "GET",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        url: "/isloggedin",
        success: function(jsonData) {
            alert("jsonData =" + jsonData.LoggedIn);
            return jsonData.LoggedIn;
        }
    });
}
```

The returned JSON is very simple, it looks like the following:

```
{ LoggedIn: true } or { LoggedIn : false }
```

Now this method, actually works and displays the alert correctly: `JsonData = true` if logged in, and `JsonData = false` if not logged in.
Up to this point there's no problem, the problem occurs when I try to call this method: I call it like so:

```
$(".friend_set .img").click(function() {
    debugger;
    if (isLoggedIn()) { 

        alert("alredy logged in");
        trackAsync();
        popupNum = 6;
    }
    else {
        alert("not logged in"); //always displays this message.
        popupNum = 1;
    }
    //centering with css

    centerPopup(popupNum);
    //load popup
    loadPopup(popupNum);
    return false;

});
```

Calling `isLoggedIn` always returns `false`, and it returns `false before the ajax request finishes (because the message`jsonData = true`is displayed after the message "not logged in". I made sure that the request is **NOT** Asynchronous by stating`async: false`!

Apparently it's still working asynchronously, though. What am I missing here guys?

Comment: Does it matter if you specify `{ async: "false" }` vs. `{ async : false }`?

Comment: @Cory Larson No, it doesn't matter, the thing is, the method returns false before the ajax request is even completed.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

You need `async:false`, not `async:"false"`. (i.e. pass boolean `false`, not string `"false"`).

Edit:
also with async requests you need to return a value *after* the call to `ajax`, *not* inside your success handler:

```
function isLoggedIn() {
    var isLoggedIn;
    $.ajax({
        async: false,
        // ...
        success: function(jsonData) {
            isLoggedIn = jsonData.LoggedIn
        }
    });
    return isLoggedIn 
}
```

Comment: Thanks bendewey! It's always jarring seeing someone edit my post (I keep forgetting about that feature), but thanks.

Comment: the return value after the success handler did it!

Comment: But will `isLoggedIn` have the actual value from `jsonData.LoggedIn`? In my case it returns 'undefined'