# How to Wait for the Response from webservice and Call another Webservice in Jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I am creating a web application and i have 4 webservice.

1. Make Call
2. Get Ringing Status
3. Answered Status
4. Hang Up

I want that when i execute the first webservice from jquery it should wait for the response and then check the another Webservice and get the status asynchronously.

Presently i am using .

```
function InfoByDate(){
    var divToBeWorkedOn = "#AjaxPlaceHolder";
    var webMethod = "http://MyWebService/Web.asmx/GetInfoByDates";
    var parameters = "{}";

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: webMethod,
        data: parameters,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(msg) {    
            $(divToBeWorkedOn).html(msg.d);
        },
        error: function(e){
            $(divToBeWorkedOn).html("Unavailable");              
        }
    });
}
```

Can you suggest something.

Comment: Can't you put the status webservice call in success of make call service ?

Comment: yes i can. but how can i keep on checking whether the service is returning me the appropriate response

Comment: I guess you mean you want to poll the webservice. For that you can use setInterval method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The term for "how can i **keep on checking**" is polling. If you want to poll webservice you can use [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setInterval?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=window.setInterval) as below.

```
setInterval(function() {
  //call your webservice here
}, 5000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following in jQuery

```
async: false,
```

as

```
 $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: webMethod,
    data: parameters,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    async: false,
    success: function(msg) {    
        $(divToBeWorkedOn).html(msg.d);
    },
    error: function(e){
        $(divToBeWorkedOn).html("Unavailable");     
        //call you second function here
    }
});
```

More detail

[What does "async: false" do in jQuery.ajax()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1478295/what-does-async-false-do-in-jquery-ajax)

[$.ajax( { async : false } ) request is still firing asynchronously?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1531693/ajax-async-false-request-is-still-firing-asynchronously)

Answer (score 0):

calling a web-service and within its success handler calling other web-service is totally a synchronous call..calling second web-service irrespective of first service success is a asynchronous call.

```
 $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: webMethod,
    data: parameters,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    async: false,
    success: function(msg) {    
        $(divToBeWorkedOn).html(msg.d);
     //**call to second service**
    },
    error: function(e){
        $(divToBeWorkedOn).html("Unavailable");     
        //call you second function here
    }
});
```

for synchronous call set `Async:false` and for an asynchronous call set `Async:true` inside jquery ajax for all the service calls