# javascript variable show value it has before

Tags: javascript, oop

There should be some logical explanation for the question but I cant find anything. I'm using OOP in my javascrtipt app and I'm trying to set variable value as function.

For first the value `init_s.__temp_var` is equal to empty object. After I call function `logic_s.get_active_statuses(..)` it should be overwritten. But it doesn't. Action:

```
var widget = {
    settings: {
        __temp_var: {}
    },

    init: function () {
        init_s = this.settings;
        logic_s = this.functions_available;
    },

    functions_available: {
        get_active_statuses: function (id) {
            jQuery.ajax({
            url: .....,
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'JSON',
            data: {
                ....
            },
            success: function (data) {
                init_s.__temp_var = data; // not working
                return data; // undefined
            },
            error: function (e) {
                console.log(e.message);
            }
        });
        }
    },

    my_actions: {
        logic: function () {
            var active_services_status = logic_s.get_active_statuses(5);
            console.log(init_s.__temp_var); // should print {id : 5}
            console.log(active_services_status ); // if used with return prints "undefined"
        }
    }
};
```

so when I call `logic_s.get_active_statuses(5);` for the first time, it loggs me empty object, but when I call it for the second time, it loggs me `{id : 5}`. If third time variable would be 10 it would be printed just after 4th call. Why is this happening? It seems like the variable is being set after it is printed..

**EDIT:**

the way it is working and returning "undefined":

```
function get_active_status (id) {
                jQuery.ajax({
                url: .....,
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'JSON',
                data: {
                    ....
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    return data; // undefined
                },
                error: function (e) {
                    console.log(e.message);
                }
            });
            };

get_active_status(5); // returns "undefined" instead of object that was sended
```

Comment: Please provide a JSFiddle

Comment: `get_active_statuses` has no `return` in it, so `var active_services_status` isn't going to be doing much...

Comment: but if i make it like this `get_active_statuses: function (id) {
            return id;
        }` it prints me "undefined" . The logic is just an example, `get_active_statuses` is a ajax call and variable is being set after success call

Comment: my paste bad, as I said before it is just example of structure Im using..

Comment: edited question for problem in same way

Answer (score 1):

When you use AJAX, your requests are [asynchronous](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/). That means it sends some request here

`logic_s.get_active_statuses(5)`

and it **doesn't** wait for the response (*success* executes only after you've received response from server) and continues to execute

```
console.log(init_s.__temp_var); // should print {id : 5}
console.log(active_services_status ); // if used with return prints "undefined"
```

What you can do is to use [setTimeout()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp), however this destroys any feature of asynchronous behaviour. 
Another way - look for the option *async* which is true by default. Your function will be:

```
function get_active_status (id) {
            jQuery.ajax({
            url: .....,
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'JSON',
            async: false,
            data: {
                ....
            },
            success: function (data) {
                return data; // undefined
            },
            error: function (e) {
                console.log(e.message);
            }
        });
        };
```

Comment: what is the next option after setTimeout? Becouse its not good for me

Comment: There is option _async_ in ajax which is true by default, it should help.

Comment: Do you want to still have asynchronous behaviour and have a result right after the request?

Comment: BTW, _async: false_ actually should work... [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1531710/3500157)